# Does an html form post the values of elements other than input?

Tags: html, forms, post, get

for example, if I have a form

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div name="superman" value="clark kent"></div>
<object name="batman" value="john smith"></object>
</form>
```

Will I get the $_POST values?

update:
w3c says object above sends data. 
I'm currently unsure about div.

Comment: I don't think that will work, but I can't test it right now. I think the only way to do it is use form input, textarea and select fields, but I'd definitely get a second opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only controls are transmitted in forms.

Background in [W3C: Forms in HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html), especially the chapter on [successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2).

Comment: object sends form data according to the successful control specification. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2

Answer (score 0):

The form data only contains data from `input`, `select` and `textarea` elements. Your form data will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't. The form only goes through certain pre selected elements, like `input`, `select` and `textarea` elements & post their value.